# What power adapter does this TechCode wireless handheld barcode scanner need?

Tags: power, barcode-scanner

In 2014 I bought a "TechCode" handheld wireless barcode scanner from a large online retailer. I tested it after purchase and saw that it worked.

Having now moved house, I can't find its power adapter. Furthermore, the only socket I can see on it looks more like an ethernet connection than a power socket. Does anyone know what power adapter I might need, or where I might get one? Here are some photos of it:

[image: scanner image 1]

[image: scanner image 2]

[image: scanner image 3]

[image: scanner image 4]

[image: scanner instruction manual and USB receiver]

I do have its paltry instruction manual, but it has no images, and doesn't even mention a product name or product code.

Comment: Why would a scanner that requires a power cable be wireless?  Are you sure there isn't a dead battery in the handle?

Comment: I assume it's a rechargeable battery.

Comment: You've got the manual. Does it say anything about that?

Comment: No. Nothing on that at all.

Answer (score 1):

Images of the manual and a clearer image of the top of the scanner could be helpful.

According to [Adafruit](https://learn.adafruit.com/barcode-scanner/cable-connection) these things use cables that look like ethernet cables, but aren't... If you google barcode scanner cable you'll find em in USB and (oldskool) [RS232](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-232) variaties.

The manual should contain [barcodes used to configure it](https://cdn-learn.adafruit.com/assets/assets/000/000/874/original/shipping_quickstart.jpg?1396766121).

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look there. I've also added 2 new pictures: one of its top, and the other of the instruction manual.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's got a proprietary mains adapter/USB to RJ45 power supply. I found this online which might be what you need, or close to it.

https://www.amazon.co.uk/Aussel-RJ45-Symbol-Barcode-Scanner/dp/B016HH3L7I

EDIT: It may be using a combined RS232 + power to RJ45 interface. See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/344685/rj45-to-rs232-with-power

Comment: Thanks. A pity the first is out of stock, but the second link is also food for thought.

Comment: Potentially you could use the 2nd link to try and make your own. If it's just to power it, you might get away with hooking up the USB power lines to some of the RJ45 pins and powering it that way.